# Simple Enum dilemma

Tags: java, enums

So when I use some APIs I see that they can return some ints by ex: `Settings.MAIN_SCREEN` and that might return `1`. I'm assuming that the `Settings` is an Enum but I can't figure out how to return a variable from an Enum constructor. All I can do is `Settings.MAIN_SCREEN.getId()`

If anyone knows how to do this please share

Comment: Why you think its enum? I would say that `Settings` is normal class with constant `public static final int MAIN_SCREEN = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

An enum cannot 'be' or 'return' an integral type.

Before Java had enums, there was a common convention of making interfaces full of named constants. Those could have any type.

Enums, on the other hand, are objects, and you have to have an accessor, as you have noted, to associate an integral value with one.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide actual example of the API you were using (e.g. a link to their JavaDoc).

From what you write, I assume that `Settings.MAIN_SCREEN` is in fact not an enum but a constant, nothing more:

```
public class Settings {
    public static final int MAIN_SCREEN = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are spot on; as they all say, its likely that what you're seeing is not an Enum, but in fact a constant static value in some object. Regardless I thought I might add something else too that might be helpful. Enums are similar to objects in that they can have constructors and member fields, however the constructor cannot be accessed externally. [Check out the documentation for more info.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

To answer your question hypothetically, you could do something like this:

```
public enum Settings{
    MAIN_SCREEN(1) // internally invoking this enum's constructor, passing the value 1.

    private int id;        

    private Settings(int id){
        this.id= id;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your code, you may then do this:

```
Settings.MAIN_SCREEN.getId() // this will return the value 1, as specified in the enumeration.
```

As far as I know, there is no way to obtain an integer value directly from an enum without using this method, as the enumeration itself is maintained internally. You can get the name of the Enum as a String (`getName()`). If this Settings thing you mention is coming from a third-party api that is closed to you, you're probably up the creek on this one.